# ToMany relation gives type error at link()

Tags: dart, objectbox

I have the table:

```dart
    @Entity()
    @JsonSerializable()
    class DateTimeStruct {
      @JsonKey(ignore: true)
      int id = 0;
      DateTime time = DateTime.now();
      String? title;
    
      DateTimeStruct();
      factory DateTimeStruct.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$DateTimeStructFromJson(json);
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DateTimeStructToJson(this);
    }
```

and

```dart
    @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
    @Entity()
    class Event {
      final Time = ToMany<DateTimeStruct>();
    }
```

When I try to query related table with link, like this:

```dart
    Store.box<Event>().query().link(Event_.Time,
          DateTimeStruct_.time.greaterOrEqual(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch));
```

I get the

```
The argument type 'QueryRelationMany<Event, DateTimeStruct>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QueryRelationProperty<Event, DateTimeStruct>'
```

error message.

Second problem: `DateTimeStruct_.time` resolved as `QueryIntegerProperty<DateTimeStruct> time`, but it is a DateTime. Has it converted to integer in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given entities won't work with `pub run build_runner build` because `Event` is missing an `id`
2. You're using `ToMany` relations - you'd only want to do that if you want to store multiple `DateTimeStruct` for each `Event` - just making sure you're aware. If it's fine to only have a single time per event (which, conceptually, sounds right to me), use `ToOne`.
3. With `ToMany`, you need to link using `.linkMany()` instead of `.link()` - that's where the compilation error comes from.
4. Yes Dart `DateTime` objects are stored as a millisecond timestamp (unless you specify otherwise using `@Property(type: PropertyType.dateNano) annotation`). You need to query them as such - you seem to be doing that correctly.

Comment: Thank You Vaind. Please refresh the documentation, there is a ToMany with link() dart example.